# I cannot run a query inside another query in Mysql. Table messages. Display inbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table messages, and I would like to display the most recent message.
If user 1 is logged in, I would like to do this:
For instance if user 1 sent an message to user 2, then user 2 to user 1, I would like to show to user 1, the newest message. So it would be the one that was sent by user 2.
My table has:

```
id |  id_from|id_to|text 
1     1       2     abc     
2     2       1     dif      
3     3       1     jsd
```

So, I have to display to user 1, the ids 2 and 3.

I try this:
thanks a lot!

```
   $consulta=mysql_query("select * from messages where id_from='".$id."' or id_to='".$id."'  ");
while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
    $id=$filas['id'];
    $id_to=$filas['id_to'];
    $status=$filas['status'];
    $text=$filas['text'];
    $time=$filas['time'];
    echo "lo primero: ";

$consulta2=mysql_query("select * from messages where id_from='".$id."' or id_to='".$id."' ");
    while($filas2=mysql_fetch_array($consulta2)){
        echo "es ";
        $id2=$filas2['id'];
        $id_to2=$filas2['id_to'];
        $status2=$filas2['status'];
        $text2=$filas2['text'];
        $time2=$filas2['time'];
        echo "es ";
        echo $id2;
            if($id_from==$id_from2 and $id_to==$id_to2 and $id2>$id){ 
                $id=$id2;           
                echo "el mas grande ";
                echo $id;
            }
    }
    echo $id;
    echo " ";
    //Almaceno en un vector los mensajes a mostrar
    $result  = array ( "'".$id."'");
```

Comment: can you post some sample table data?

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: The code never enters to the second while ,thats my Question : )

Comment: And how can I make it? I would like to display the most recent message

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: it looks like you're trying to do something completely the wrong way, I would go with a simple query. Try posting some sample data, explaining what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single simple query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_from != 1 AND id_to = 1
```

Comment: What I put on that table is an example
the table perhaps has lots of rows, so I have to show for the user that is logged in, all the inboxes that he sent, or he received

Answer (score 0):

I assume first column **id** is set to auto increment. To show the most recent activity of user with id=$userid use

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `messages` 
WHERE  `id_from` =  '$userid' ||  `id_to` =  '$userid'
ORDER BY  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

From this query we will get the single last activity of the user.From that resultant row u can check whether the activity is a sent message or recieved one and show the text accordingly.

If ur simply tring to show inbox messages with most recent one on top  use

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `messages` 
    WHERE  `id_to` =  '$userid'
    ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```

Comment: I want to do what facebook does. for instance you send an inbox to user 2, then to user 3, then user 2 answers you, so you have to display the message that user 2 sent to you and the one that you sent to user 3

Comment: Ok. So u r trying to display messages like chat .Clicking on a user will show all conversations between u and him in order.